# How a '\t' escape sequence different than that of four spaces manually?

Tags: c++, escaping

I was making matrix in C++ and to show it look like matrix I used nested loops of `for`.

```
for (i=0; i<m; i++){
        for (j=0; j<n; j++){
            cout<<matrix[i][j]<<"\t";
        }
        cout<<"\n";
```

suppose I input the elements of matrix to be 1, 2, 3, 45, 45, 6 of order 2x3.
so the output is

```
1       2       3
45      45      6
```

but when I use four spaces instead of `\t` like this

```
for (i=0; i<m; i++){
        for (j=0; j<n; j++){
            cout<<matrix[i][j]<<"    ";
        }
        cout<<"\n";
```

the output is

```
1    2    3
45    45    6
```

Now for me the latter code does make sense and giving expected result of inserting 4 spaces after every element.
but `\t` supposed to insert a tab space. There I see that between 1 and 2 there are seven spaces while between 45 and 45 it's only 6 spaces. Why isn't it consistent? So I just want to know how a tab space different and how it works?

By the way, sorry for asking such dumb questions. I'm just starting out in C++ so don't know the ground much.

Comment: Tab stops usually have fixed positions. Typically every eight column. And it's not really related to C++, but rather the terminal showing the output.

Comment: use the  `setw` io-manipulator if you want to be in control over the spacing

Comment: Ohh, so it's on the output, i.e., terminal. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\t` (tab) is short for tabulator which is inherited from (professional) typewriters with built-in tabulator stops at certain (evenly spaced) columns to help the typist to create tables etc. In some typewriters the tabulator stops could even be set by the typist.

When pressing the <kbd>->|</kbd> (tab) key the typewriter's carriage would move to one of these pre-set stops.

This is mimiced by sending a `\t` to the renderer of the output (your terminal).

A common tabulator setting for terminals is to have a tabulator stop every 8:th character, like so:

```
--------!-------!-------!-------!-------!-------!-------!-------!-------!-------!--etc--
```

but these stops may also be possible to set in your terminal so you as a programmer won't know where the stops are when using standard C++. You just press the tabulator key (send `\t`) to the terminal and let it find the next tabulator stop and move the carriage (cursor) to that position.

This lack of control can be remedied by using the [`std::setw()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) I/O manipulator to set the minimum width of the next output, as can be demonstrated by this example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>  // std::setfill, std::setw

int main() {
    std::cout << std::setfill('-'); // replace space with - as fill character

    for(int i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
        std::cout << std::setw(3) << i;
    }
}
```

This doesn't depend on the tabulator settings since it'll fill the space between the output with whatever your [*fill character*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setfill) is set to (it's space by default).

The above program will output:

```
--0--1--2--3--4--5--6--7--8--9-10-11-12-13-14-15-16-17-18-19
```

Every output here takes up 3 characters and the space between is filled with the `-` character.

---

Edit: The tabulator character `\t` is not (usually) actually changing anything visually on your output device. It merely moves the position of the carriage (cursor) to the right until the first tabulator stop is found.

Playing with control characters and given this `std::cout << "hello\rH\tworld\n"`, let's break what happens down:

- `hello` - `hello` is printed and the cursor is now at column 5 (0-based).
- `\r` - nothing is printed but the cursor moved to column 0.
- `H` - `H` is printed over what was previously `h`.
- `\t` - nothing is printed but the cursor moved to the first tab stop (unknown column, often 8)
- `world` - `world` is printed wherever the cursor happens to be.
- `\n` - combines a carriage return and newline so the cursor will now be at column 0 at the next line.

Comment: Okay, I understood it almost thanks to you. So, first the `\t` key moves the cursor to the next tabular stop which is at the 8th character. Thereafter, it fills the space remain in between by (default) space character. Is that correct? I thought '\t' fills or separate the characters with 8 spaces but it's actually different it shifts the cursor and then fills the remaining gap. Thank you so much. I just wanted to know how it works and you explained perfectly.

Comment: @Saurabh You're welcome! The `\t` just moves the cursor to the next tabular stop. It (usually) doesn't fill or do anything else. Try printing `"hello\rH\tworld\n"`. `\r` moves the cursor back to the beginning of the line (without a linefeed) and then the `\t` moves it to the first tab stop. `ello` is likely to remain unchanged so you get something like `Hello   world`.

Comment: Thanks for explaining but I'm confused that why capital `H` replaced small `h`. As you said that `\r` moves the cursor back to beginning of the line so cursor went to start of the line? Now does it start replacing with what we wrote after `\r`. If that, then does `\t` also do the same of first moves cursor to tab stop and then start writing if there is already a string or character it would replace it with what we have written after `\t`.Am I right? Again sorry for asking dumb questions but I'm a total beginner.

Comment: @Saurabh I've updated the answer. Does it make it clearer? (and don't worry about asking "dumb" questions, the question is fine)

Comment: Thank you very much. Understood it perfectly. So it `\t` moves the cursor to next tab stop regardless of what is already written over there and then it starts writing meaning it may overwrite also as you've shown by replacing small h by capital H. Got it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Spaces and tabs have different representations in ASCII. `<space>` is 0x20, while `<tab>` is 0x09. When the program checks the current character, both possibilities need to be tested.
however both of them works same. It should be the terminal which is causing the difference.